# Modificar a URL de um href usando PHP HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, url, dom

Eu to querendo modificar uma URL de um objeto que eu to extraindo de outro site, no caso, do Exame.com.

Segue o código:

```
 $exame = file_get_html("http://exame.abril.com.br/");
                $exame_posts = $exame->find("p.content-item-title");
                foreach($exame_posts as $i => $value){  
                    if($i < 10){
                    echo $value;
                    }

                }
```

O código é simples, ele pega as tags "p" com a classe "content-item-title" e limita a 10 e imprime as 10.

A questão é: como eu modifico a url de alguns desses links que eu consigo? Alguns links eu consigo acessar o site do Exame.com, outros (poucos) não. Vou mostrar um exemplo de como fica alguns links:

Os links como são gerados na página HTML:

[image: Os links como são gerados na pagina]

Como a url fica quando eu clico em um deles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois que a url ficar correta, como evitar um possível conflito naqueles outros links que estão sem erro algum?

Abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você consegue fazer usando o `str_ireplace` no `$value` antes de dar `echo`:

```
 $site = "http://exame.abril.com.br/";
 $exame = file_get_html($site);
                $exame_posts = $exame->find("p.content-item-title");
               foreach($exame_posts as $i => $value){  
                    if($i < 10){
                    if (!preg_match('/(href="http|href=\'http)/i', $value)) {
                        $value = str_ireplace(array('href="', "href='", $site.'/'), array('href="'.$site, "href='".$site, $site), $value);
                    }
                    echo $value;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Jader, muito obrigado, amigo! Funcionou perfeitamente, precisei só retirar o "http://" no segundo array passado como parâmetro da str_ireplace. Poderia me explicar como esse código funciona?

Comment: desculpe o http:// foi erro meu, quando editei deixei passar... quanto ao funcionamento basicamente ele primeiro verifica se o href tem http antes de incluir o endereço do site, e para garantir ele testa com aspas duplas e simples, por sim ele remove uma possível barra dupla depois do endereço, inclusive melhorei essa parte na resposta.